# Opencart : Error in shoping cart template :- Could not load template

Tags: opencart

I'm new to opencart. my opencart system was working fine. but suddenly i got a error. it said `Notice: Error: Could not load template C:\wamp\www\suprize/catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/featured_category.tpl! in C:\wamp\www\suprize\system\engine\controller.php on line 91` what is this and what is the reason to come this error. ?

Answer (score 1):

Goto your `catalog/controller/module/featured_category.php`

check the following code lines below as overview there to get idea try to check spell also

> if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') .
>   '/template/module/featured_category.tpl')) {          $this->template =
>   $this->config->get('config_template') .
>   '/template/module/featured_category.tpl';         } else {            $this->template =
>   'default/template/module/featured_category.tpl';      }

then goto to the folder

> catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/

find the same file as defined above e.g `featured_category.tpl` also  check spelling of file name. A **suggestion** is to upload this **extension** again :) that will also fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

Check the following notes:

1. `catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/featured_category.tpl` - Does this file exists?
2. verify the file permission.
3. Check the file path.